# Oracle sql view rows that id exist and doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: "Orders", "Names"

Some orders doesn't exist in "Names", but I need to get them too.

Example:

**Orders:**

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

**Names**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |

If ID from Orders doesn't exist in Names, column Name will be null

Result:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |
| 3 |  |

If I try **"WHERE ORDERS.ID = NAMES.ID"**, ID number 3 doesn't match, so it will not show up.

Comment: how can you have an order without a name?

Comment: Look up "outer join"

Comment: A `LEFT JOIN` is what you want.

Comment: `select o.id, n.name from orders o left join names n on n.i = o.id`.